# Can older iPhones receive Animojis created and sent from iPhone X?

Tags: iphone, animoji

iPhone 7+ (iOS 11.1) owner here. If a friend buys an iPhone X and creates/sends me an Animoji, how will it appear on my phone (if at all)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer:  Yes.

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208190):

> You can create your own Animoji and share it with anyone using an iOS
>   device, Mac, or smartphone.

The iPhone X can create the Animoji which can then share the *animation* to anyone running iOS, macOS, or a smartphone - *ANY* smartphone.  See this [article](https://www.elitedaily.com/p/sending-animojis-to-people-without-iphone-x-is-totally-possible-so-rejoice-3218314) for more details

The Animoji is saved as a `.mov` file which is sent via MMS and can be viewed by virtually any smartphone (not just iPhones).

Answer (score 6):

Yes. [This site states](https://www.elitedaily.com/p/sending-animojis-to-people-without-iphone-x-is-totally-possible-so-rejoice-3218314) that Animoji can be seen and heard on other devices because it's sent via MMS (Multimedia Messaging Service).

In fact, people with an iPhone X can save their Animoji as a .mov file or as a sticker to use in other messages.

I can verify this works.  I sent an Animoji to my wife who has an iPhone SE.  She was able to see and hear the message.

Answer (score 1):

It will appear as a regular video file

(Usually in a .vid or .mov file format that is accepted across all mobile & desktop platforms and Operating Systems.